# Wrong version of pydot is being imported

Tags: python, pip, pydot

I installed `pydot2` successfully using the Ipython notebook.

```
%%bash

pip install pydot2


Collecting pydot2
  Downloading pydot2-1.0.33.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing in /Users/ram/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pydot2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /Users/ram/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg (from pydot2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pydot2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pydot2
  Stored in directory: /Users/ram/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e5/2d/ca/55e0109fb619edaa42ca287d9e55519eeebebc9bbca35996f6
Successfully built pydot2
Installing collected packages: pydot2
Successfully installed pydot2-1.0.33
```

---

At the terminal, I see pydot2 is present. In python,  `import pydot2` fails and `import pydot` shows version 1.0.29 of pydot, not 1.0.33.

```
$ pip freeze| grep pydot

pydot2==1.0.33

$ python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import pydot

pydot.__version__
'1.0.29'

import pydot2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pydot2'
```

---

**Question:** Do I need to uninstall pydot before installing pydot2. How do I do that ?

Note: I have a dual Ananconda python env (2.7/3.5) In 2.7, there is
no pydot installed. I am on latest MacOS 10.11.

I can't make out where pydot 1.0.29 is on my system.

Comment: @DavidW, welcome your change and thank you for informing and correcting it. Sorry about adding wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should show you where pydot 1.0.29 is on your system:

```
import pydot
pydot.__file__
```

Your install attempt has an interesting message: `use --upgrade to upgrade`. Did you try adding the `--upgrade` option?

Comment: I did not try adding the --upgrade option. How do I do that ? Thanks, Ram

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pydot2`

Comment: $ pip install --upgrade pydot2
Requirement already up-to-date: pydot2 in ./lib/python3.5/site-packages
Collecting pyparsing (from pydot2)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from pydot2)
  Downloading setuptools-19.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (472kB)
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, setuptools
  Found existing installation: pyparsing 2.0.3
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyparsing) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling pyparsing-2.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pyparsing-2.0.3
  Found existing installation: setuptools 19.1.1
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /Users/ram/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth

Comment: The pydot.__version__ is still 1.0.29 after the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. When I looked into the actual [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2/1.0.32), the pydot file being installed is pydot.py, not pydot2.py. Which is why we're unable to import pydot2, and pydot ver. 1.0.29 is installed.

I'll update if I find a solution to this.

Update: After much digging I found there isn't a great solution to pydot2. Instead you should use pydotplus which can be installed with pip.